# Dart: Accessing function from list

Tags: dart

I want to have a new random number every time to print it, but it prints the same on. I tried so many thing, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Help me, please!

```
import 'dart:math';

int next_int() { return new Random().nextInt(100); }

void main()
{
  List<int> list = [next_int(), next_int(), next_int()];

  // expected new int each time but got the same one
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
        List<int> cur_list = new List.from(list);
        print(cur_list[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is surprisingly similar question and code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65683945

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work as you expect:

```
import 'dart:math';

int next_int() { return new Random().nextInt(100); }

void main()
{
  List<int> list = [next_int(), next_int(), next_int()];

  // expected new int each time but got the same one
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
        List<int> cur_list = new List.from(list);
        print(cur_list[i]); // <= Use the index value stored in "i" instead of 0
  }
}
```